# C++ I/O copy txt file of different types

Tags: c++, types

i am learning how to read/write files using C++ and ran into a problem copying the first line of a txt file. I pasted the txt file below. As you can see, the first line has two strings while the rows below are of different types. How would I declare the type for column 2 since it is a string on row 1 and an integer after that? While I can copy the file's contents to `output.txt` by declaring everything as a string, I was curious how to deal with different types. Your help is much appreciated.

`input.txt` file:

```
firstname value
Jack 1
Jacob 3
Jerry 2
Jeremy 3
Joseph 3
Jim 3
```

I am getting a blank `output.txt` file because of type conflict I think.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

string fname;
int value;

using namespace std;

int main() {
    ifstream in_file; //variable name
    in_file.open("input.txt");
    if (in_file.fail()){
        cout << " The file is not found " << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    
    ofstream out_file;
    out_file.open("output.txt");
    while (in_file >> fname >> value){
    out_file << fname << " " << value <<  endl;
    };

 
}
```

Comment: Just handle the first line in a different way, as two strings, not a string and an int.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @ForceBru This worked for me, though please let me know if there's a more efficient way to accomplish this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

string fname;
string col2;
int lname;

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int count=0;
    ifstream in_file; //variable name
    in_file.open("input.txt");
    if (in_file.fail()){
        cout << " The file is not found " << endl;
        return 1;
    }


    ofstream out_file;
    out_file.open("output.txt");

    if (count==0){
        in_file >> fname >> col2;
        out_file << fname << " " << col2 << endl;
        count++;
    }

    while (in_file >> fname >> lname){
        out_file << fname << " " << lname <<  endl;
    };



}
```

Comment: Why do you need a count for the first line? You also don't need the values, a simple getline would skip them.

Comment: the count is for specifying string values in the first row, i am not sure how to implement getline

Comment: @st and how does count know, that that's the first line? You should use getline, not implement it.

Comment: @user2672107 Why did you delete your account?